# Apple Mail in Mavericks: Any way to change MinimumHTMLFontSize?

Tags: macos, email, font-size, osx-mavericks

Prior to 10.9, the following command-line command used to work:

defaults write com.apple.mail MinimumHTMLFontSize 12

But in Mavericks, it seems this no longer works.

Anyone found another way to increase the default minimum font size for new messages? Some HTML messages are coming in with tiny, almost unreadable font sizes.

Answer (score 2):

As of OS X 10.9, Mail respects explicit font sizes in a message's HTML. This default is no longer used. I recommend you file a bug if you would like something different. http://bugreporter.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

yes! I found a solution!
I found it on http://9to5mac.com/2013/12/08/how-to-take-advantage-of-zoom-and-large-text-in-os-x-mavericks/

It goes like this:
In Mail preferences, the settings are on the Fonts & Colors tab. You can adjust the “Message list font” and “Message font” separately. (The Message list font changes your inbox appearance, the Message font changes the body of emails.)  Using the Select buttons, you can set these to any font size. However, the Message list font size is only truly customizable if you select “Use classic layout” on the Viewing tab.

Comment: Didn't work for me. The message font size stayed the same, even after a restart of Mail.app.

Answer (score 0):

See my [similar question and solution on the apple stack exchange site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157104/can-i-increase-the-minimum-font-size-of-text-when-reading-html-messages-in-mail) for a partial solution to your question:

In a nutshell, while I've not found a direct analog to that hidden preference, I was able to override the most common instances of tiny font-sizes in the message reader by editing a CSS resource file within the Mail.app itself.